# Tangent Normal Map Seams

Tags: normal-map, seams

The normal map I'm using has visible seams, I've tried inverting the green channel, in fact I think I've tried a lot of fixes but non of them stick.

[image: seam problem]

Though the seams disappear when the normal map node is changed to anything other than tangent space but it doesn't look good, could my texture be formatted wrong?

[image: changed to blender world space]

also my normal map looks wrong it's too blue

[image: dark blue nm]

when it should look like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes it doesn't look like it has the right color spectrum, was the image 16-Bit or 32-Bit Float when you baked the normals?

Comment: just checked and it says 32

Comment: sure but the colors are still not good so it may be the problem, do you still have your high poly version so that we can try to bake again?

Comment: sadly not, i may have to start from scratch unfortunately, thanks for trying though.

Comment: Have you baked that texture yourself ? Was your first screenshot taken with the "non-color" color management on your image texture node? Do you remember which color management you baked and saved with? And have you baked the normal map in tangent or object space?

Comment: It would help to share your .blend file with us, you can do so by uploading it to [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and add the provided text into your post.

Comment: @L0Lock No, it's a pre-baked texture from a mod that I'm porting to different install method, TPF to TFC. My first screenshot was taken in the "non-color" color management. The color management I saved in is set to "Non" and my sequencer "non-color", bake type is set to "normal" and the space is set to "tangent". I'll upload the .blend file now.

Comment: @L0Lock I think I just found the problem actually, the dds file is originally a V8U8 file and porting to be anything different breaks it.

Comment: Nice, you could post the answer below and mark it as valid for extra points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem and the potential reason on why it was broken: The original file was saved as a DDS file formatted in V8U8, the program (TPF Extract) I used to extract the original file converted it into B8G8R8A8 which broke the colour. To get the original I loaded the game with the mod installed and had SpecialK run along with it using texture dumping, dumped the texture and had the non-touched version of the normal. However I ran into another problem a DDS file formatted in V8U8 cannot be opened in blender and using any converter will remove any original detail such as shine and any of the detailed patterns. Unlucky.